# how to make multi site with one codeigniter application?

Tags: codeigniter, multisite

I'm trying to develop a shopping system with codeigniter.

I developing the back-end & front-end of my shopping system.

But my problem is I want to use this code for many stores.

For example my main address is shop.com.

I want people can have their own shop in my system with their own subfolder like this: shop.com/shop1  |  shop.com/shop2 & ...

I want the users subfolder placed out of application folder.

My directory list like this:

```
shop.com
-application
--cache
--config
--controllers   
--core
--helpers
--...(other application contents)
-assets
-attachments
-system
-shop1
-shop2
& ...
```

I making all shop parts and every thing is ok when i call shop.com.

Now I want to making shop1 with specific subfolder and database.

I can making separate database for each shop and connect the code to his own database. after this I call shop.com/shop1 and the main page load like a charm.

But when I call shop controllers ( example: shop.com/shop1/checkout ) I get 404 error.

And at the end I noticed two point:

1- I use the original codeigniter root index.php code as my shop1/index.php

2- I change the $system_path to ../system and $application_folder to ../application

It seems codeigniter unable to locate the controllers properly.

What can I do to solving this problem?

Comment: shop.com/shop1/checkout (domain/controller/function) gives you a 404 because shop1 (controller) dosn't exist. investigate in using subdomains, like shop1.shop.com/controller/function/id

Comment: I appreciate for your help but I want to do this with subfolder for some reasons. @Vickel

Comment: You are welcome, anyway in my experience, the subdomain approach is the one to consider, specially if you want to sell your site later to different shop-owners. Also it will allow you the create different databases, even on a shared server, much easier

Answer (score 0):

You mean HMVC?

1. Download files and copy C.i.3.0 forder in application : https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads
2. Create and coppy paste in .htaccess

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

3.Create folder name 'modules' in application/
4.Create folder name 'folder' in application/modules
4.Create folder name 'controllers, models, views' in application/modules/folder
5.Create file name 'file name same folder' in application/modules/folder/controllers

for error
paste this in MX/Loder.php

```
return $this->_ci_load(array('_ci_view' => $view, '_ci_vars' => $this->_ci_prepare_view_vars($vars), '_ci_return' => $return));
```

Comment: Thank you my friend.@wazowski

Comment: I implemented the shop system with HMVC from the first day.
According to my first post I need to use subfolder for any shop instance which is that subfolder be the new shop address like: shop.com/shop1, shop.com/shop2.
All these subfolders(shops) use whole of code & modules as an engine.

@wazowski